# Print the background image on printer

Tags: image, printing, background

I have a page in which background image is not printing by print command.
If I set "File->print setup->Print background" then it print the image on paper in mozilla. How Can we print the page on printer. I've already set the media as print.

Answer (score 0):

By default many browsers does not print background images and colours.

To make WebKit browsers (Safari, Google Chrome) print the background image or colour you should add the following CSS style to the element:

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
```

Comment: Please stop posting duplicates of this all over the place.

Comment: This is inherent to the question, how should I handle that instead?

Comment: If the questions are duplicates, you can flag them to be closed.  If they're not duplicates, please address each specific question being asked.  Having 10 copies pasted of the same answer is a sign that there's too much duplication of questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer !

You take an image (images will be printed)

then you calulate the width of the image example (50px)  then you take the div size of the div you want to add a background to example 400px

now you know you need 8 images next to each other 8x50 is 400

Then you do the same.

So basicly you post alot of images

It sounds hard but there is an example at this question [repeat img like it is a background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920987/repeat-img-like-it-is-a-background)

if you use 1 img like a color you can set it in your css with:

```
 #divnam img
{
  widht:100%;
 height:100%;
}
```

I hope this will help cause it took me forever to find a solution !