# repeat img like it is a background

Tags: html, css

What i want to do seems simple but i guess its alot harder then i thought.

Cause background images wont be printed (i mean by a printer on paper) by default and i want to allow the user to print the background they have chosen i want to use a image.

So i have a div of 800 x 400 and an image of 1x1 wich is completely 1 color lets say red.

I want that image to be repeated to fill the div .

the images are diffrent sizes i have images with patterns of 50x50 with repeating patterns.

So stretching the image wont help.

So how can i repeat an image like it is a background?

Please first try your solution cause printing background-images is dependent on the browser your use, but you have to assume backgrounds (colors and images) arent printed !

**So i DON'T want to use any kind of background i just want to repeat the image , to make it act like a background without being a background !**

even if it is possible to print the background, i still would like to know how to make the img repeat.

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/aAsjv/

The img on the left div needs to be repeated horizontaly and verticaly, so it fills the whole

```
  div #board.
```

Comment: It would really help knowing what you've tried so far, otherwise others might make countless identical attempts.

Comment: Try one of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596876/how-can-i-print-background-images-in-ff-or-ie
Or you could use JQuery to dynamically create img tags and float them left.

Comment: the problem is that i want to repeat the image they use 1 img and dont repeat it, i can print 1 image but i want that 1 image to cover the complete div.

Comment: if the image is 1px x 1px, then why not just use a solid colour?

Comment: cause it is just an example i stated later in my question that i also use patterns of 50px x 50px adding a color there wont help

Comment: ok, why do you need it to be an `img` and not a css background?

Comment: @Chris because a background does not print by default.

Comment: try printing a page with a background like http://stackoverflow.com/ the header has a backgroun-color and it will be hidden. it is default for browser to not print backgorund-color background-image to save inkt. but i want the user to print it cause they chose the background

Comment: ah ok, I get you now.

Comment: try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670151/how-can-i-force-browsers-to-print-background-images-in-css

Comment: Chris if you see the accepted answer they say i have to do what i ask. so set a image and give it low z-index so it is in the background but still a normal img. thats exactly what i want to do but i need to repeat that img.

Comment: @SvenB, Can you post some code, maybe a jsfiddle? It would help determine how best to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click on another pattern on the right and see what happens.

Made it with jQuery (so not the best method for doing stuff like this) however it is working,
if you understand jQuery (which I guess you do) it is pritty simple code to understand

```
$(function(){
   repeat_bg();    
    $("#imgs img").click(function(){
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        $("div#hidden_bg img#dummy").attr("src",src);
        repeat_bg();            
    });
});

function repeat_bg()
{
    var board_width = $('#board').width();
    var board_height = $('#board').height();
    var bg_width = $('#dummy').width();
    var bg_height = $('#dummy').height();


    var count_horizontal = board_width / bg_width;
    count_horizontal= Math.ceil(count_horizontal);

    var count_vertical = board_height / bg_height;
    count_vertical= Math.ceil(count_vertical);
    $('div#background_hack').html("");
    $('div#background_hack').css('width' ,board_width+bg_width);

    /*
    * repeat
    * alert("horizontal we need: "+count_horizontal + " images to fill up");
    * alert("vertical we need: "+count_vertical + " images to fill up");
    * alert("totaal needed images = "+count_horizontal + " * "+ count_vertical + "= "+count_horizontal * count_vertical);
    */

    for (var i=0;i<count_horizontal * count_vertical;i++)
    { 
       var clone = $('#dummy').clone();
        $('div#background_hack').append(clone);
    }    
}
```

[link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Diabl0570/M6TyF/11/)

Comment: Wow freaking awsome ! exactly what i needed !

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate elements using `.clone()` in JQuery. For example:

### HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img class="repeat" src="#" />
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
img.repeat{ float:left; }
#wrapper{ width: 800px; height: 400px; }
```

### JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img.repeat').clone().appendTo('#wrapper');// repeat as many times as neccesary
});
```

An example using divs:
http://jsfiddle.net/hDyam/

Comment: It needs to be repeated vertically and horizontaly

Comment: Shouldn't that image tag be written as:

<img class="repeat" src="#" />

What's with the closing tag?

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo: Yes, you're right, I was changing from a div, edited it there.
@SvenB: It should float underneath when the total width of the images exceeds the width of the wrapper. If not, you could use `$('img.repeat').css('clear','both');` each time you want to start a new line.

Answer (score 0):

I have just read this : " Use background-image if you intend to have people print your page and you do not want the image to be included by default. "

So you have to use the IMG tag instead of background-image if you want the users to print the image as well.

Comment: The question is how to repeat the image tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create some javascript that creates something like this (to give you an idea):

```
<style>
#bgcontainer
{
  width: 180;
  height: 180;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#innerbgcontainer
{
  width: 2000;
  height: 2000;
}
</style>

<div id="bgcontainer">
  <div id="innerbgcontainer">
  <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width=50 height=50 />
  <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width=50 height=50 />
  <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width=50 height=50 />
  <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width=50 height=50 />
  <br />
  <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width=50 height=50 />
  <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width=50 height=50 />
  <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width=50 height=50 />
  <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width=50 height=50 />
  <br />
  <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width=50 height=50 />
  <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width=50 height=50 />
  <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width=50 height=50 />
  <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width=50 height=50 />
  <br />
  <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width=50 height=50 />
  <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width=50 height=50 />
  <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width=50 height=50 />
  <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width=50 height=50 />
</div></div>
```

Answer (score -3):

You have to set an ID for your div, and inside the CSS you have to use

```
background-repeat:repeat;
```

read more here

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

Comment: He specifically didn't want to use a background image.